# Not able to draw horizontal line on canvas if the value of x2 is more than 125020

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, line

I'm trying to draw lines on a canvas but i'm not able to draw it if the value of x2 is more than 125020. Please find the XAML code below.`I'm able to see lines if the value of x2 is equal to or below 125020.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="C1_S" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                    <Canvas Name="canvas_core0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="640" Width="1000000" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" >
                        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="20" Y1="20" X2="20" Y2="620" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle" StrokeDashCap="Triangle" />
                        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="20" Y1="220" X2="125021"  Y2="220" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle" StrokeDashCap="Triangle" />
                        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="20" Y1="420" X2="{Binding ElementName=canvas_core0, Path=Width}"  Y2="420" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle" StrokeDashCap="Triangle" />
                        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="20" Y1="620" X2="{Binding ElementName=canvas_core0, Path=Width}"  Y2="620" StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle" StrokeDashCap="Triangle" />
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,20,40,40" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                            <Pen Brush="Gray" Thickness=".1"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <MatrixTransform/>
                        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    </Canvas>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Can anyone help? Is there any limit for the length of a line while drawing on a canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, must be a bug with WPF drawing long horizontal lines.

I don't have a real answer for you but a work around might be to NOT draw horizontal lines. Instead draw nearly horizontal lines. If you change Y1 or Y2, but not both, from "220" to "220.00001" then the line is visible. Note that "220.000001" (one more 0) did not draw so that seems to be another limit of some sort.

I tested it with X2="125021000" (added three 0s) and the line still showed up.

Comment: It seems to be a bug with very wide horizontal lines inside a ScrollViewer. Good spot on the not quite horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the `StrokeThickness` (even only slightly) works.

I realise this answer is somewhat unsatisfactory but may help if you are desperate and is at least a clue.

I tried playing with `UseLayoutRounding` and `SnapsToDevicePixels` but couldn't make it work.

Interesting.

Comment: I've tried this..but its not enough...i'm trying to plot on a canvas whose width increases based on some values and i'm trying to plot this line till the end of canvas.